# find top 3 values with an inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called users_preferred_zips that looks like this:

```
 username  |  price  |   zip   |  program  |  active
-----------+---------+---------+-----------+---------
 joe       |    5    |  92108  |  dog      |    1
 tom       |    7    |  92108  |  dog      |    1
 mary      |    5    |  92108  |  dog      |    1
 paul      |    6    |  92108  |  dog      |    1
 ron       |    6    |  92108  |  dog      |    1
```

I have another table called users that looks like this

```
 username  |  balance
-----------+----------
 joe       |    10
 tom       |    12
 mary      |    2
 paul      |    14
 ron       |    3
```

I need a query to pull AND sum the 3 highest values from the `users_preferred_zips` table where the `username` from the `users` table has a `balance` value greater than or equal to 5. I know i need to do some sort of `inner join` but my query below is not working.  Here is the query i have:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS SumOfTopValues
FROM (
    SELECT users_preferred_zips . * , users.last_purchase, users.lesson_type, users.pref_acct_balance
    INNER JOIN users ON ( users_preferred_zips.username = users.username ) 
    WHERE users_preferred_zips.zip =  '92108'
    AND users_preferred_zips.program =  'dog'
    AND users_preferred_zips.active =  1
    AND users.pref_acct_balance >= '5'
    ORDER BY price DESC
    LIMIT 3
) AS sub
```

So the correct query would pull the following:

3 highest:

```
joe   |  5
tom   |  7
paul  |  6
```

Sum of 3 highest values = 18

I feel like this should be pretty simple but i'm having a tough time! Thanks for your help

Comment: What error are you getting (or how is the result you're getting wrong)?

Comment: Please use numeric auto incrementing columns as references for foreign keys, using strings that may be subject to change will cause BIG headaches - what if Joe has a sex-change and becomes Josephine?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username) ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: this is the error i am getting:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON ( users_preferred_zips.username = users.username ) WHERE users_preferred' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this using:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS SumOfTopValues
FROM users_preferred_zips
WHERE username IN (
  SELECT username
  FROM users
  WHERE pref_acct_balance >= 5
)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, however where would i put the logic for zip, program and active which i have in my example?

Comment: sorry, meant to say thanks to li-on.  li-on, can you adjust your code to help me return the right result?

Comment: got it figured out--thanks for pointing me in the right direction!